# How to make a section of the axis log scale and other section to be linear scale to better present the data

Tags: python, r, plotly, bokeh

I would like to represent my data where values go from 0.00001 to 1 where I am interested in plotting data from 0.00001 to 0.1 in a log scale and from 0.1 to 0.95 in linear scale and then again 0.95 to 1 in log scale. Most of the variations happen in the extreme and the data between 0.1 to 0.9 is almost stable but i need to take a look at it though with the rest of the data.

The x axis should be like the one shown below.

[image]

Comment: What package are you using for plotting? Show us some sample data and sample code that you want to fix.

Comment: Given the tags, I think you are seeking a tool recommendation, which is grounds for closure. I will comment that I am not aware of any tool that would do this out of the box. Your best bet is probably to stitch three plots with the desired ranges and scales together side by side.

Comment: What I did in similar cases is to use a transformation function, maybe something with tan or arctan in your case, and transform the x-axis that way. But consider that others might need to understand your plot, and it's maybe just better to split it into two logarithmic plots next to each other.

Comment: @bigreddot I don't fully agree. It's a non-trivial problem regardless of tool. I do agree with your solution, as posted below.

Comment: @StephanT I am not sure what you are disagreeing with. "It's a non-trivial problem regardless of tool" is exactly what I meant by "I am not aware of any tool that would do this out of the box."

Comment: @bigreddot I didn't agree with closure. As there is no tool with out-of-the-box solution, the question seems valid to me. It would only be lacking a code attempt.

Comment: Lacking a code attempt is also grounds for closure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by splitting the graphing in three parts and assigning each to its own x-axis. These x-axes can be placed next to each other by specifying the domain (relative coverage of space).
This is in Python, but Plotly should have the same functionality in R.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = [0.001,0.01,0.1]
x2 = [10,100,1000]
x3 = [1000,10000,100000]

y1 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [4,5,6]
y3 = [7,8,9]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1, xaxis='x1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2, xaxis='x2'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x3, y=y3, xaxis='x3'))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis1=dict(
        range=[-3,0],
        side='bottom',
        overlaying='x',
        domain=[0,0.35],
        type='log'
        ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        range=[1,1000],
        side='bottom',
        overlaying='x',
        domain=[.35,.65],
        ),
    xaxis3=dict(
        range=[3,6],
        side='bottom',
        overlaying='x',
        domain=[.65,1],
        type='log'
        ),
    )
```

[image: x axes with different scales]